# Using Python change HID bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, hid

Hey all I am new to the Python world and need some help.

I have an HID device that I am needing to replace **0x00** with **0x01** and I have this example code to modify in order to do that (I think):

```
import pywinusb.hid as hid

def readData(data):

print(data)
device = hid.HidDeviceFilter(vendor_id=0x5140).get_devices()[0]

if not device:
   print ("No device found")
else:
   print(device)
   device.open()
   report = device.find_output_reports()
   buffer = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
   report[0].set_raw_data(buffer)
   report[0].send()

device.set_raw_data_handler(readData)
device.close()
```

So would I replace the `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` with `b'\x00\x01'` in order to change it in the HID device?